# Cards in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Are Cards added to React-Bootstrap yet?

Or is there any other undocumented way of adding it?

What I am thinking of right now is -> `className = 'bootstrap card class syntax'`, but I guess, it won't work because it won't recognise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of found the answer, but it doesn't go by the name of `card`

You can use `<Thumbnail>`, it gives the same feel as that of a card.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap classes can be used the same way in react like in any *non*-react project, even without the use of `react-bootstrap`.  It can be imported as a CDN in your index.html file...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

... or it can also be saved locally and imported that way.  Or you can configure webpack to import css files directly into your project.

You'd just have to make sure to use `className=` instead of `class=`, but otherwise, it works exactly the same way.

```
<div className="col-xs-12 well"></div>
```

`react-bootstrap` is an add-on that provides components that do the same thing.  So, even if it's not in react-bootstrap yet, you can still use the functionality, but just as a straight css class.

Comment: So, if it works that way, then why use `react-boostrap`? I mean, this `className` pretty much covers everything

Comment: @Ciedzs My understanding is that it's mostly a stylistic choice.  Bootstrap-as-a-Component looks cleaner than Bootstrap-as-ClassNames.  I don't know if there's a more practical benefit beyond that.  If there is, then ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯